# play-services-vision: Band-stop filters to handle cases where the detected coordinates of the landmarks veer off from the real landmarks?

Tags: android, face-detection

When I tilt my face at an angle, the FaceDetector's landmark detection may sometimes go awry, misplacing several landmarks for a few milliseconds before going back to detecting them correctly.

Should I apply a sort of band-stop filter in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Since it is detecting face landmarks live, there can be a bit of a delay between the time that a frame is captured from the camera and the time that the detected landmarks are available and are rendered to the camera screen.  By the time that the landmarks have been drawn, your face has moved a little.

If you'd process frames from a video offine, and not live, you'd find that it appears to track the landmarks much more closely.